# Typing Single Quotes On US/International Keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout, language, dead-keys

The US/international keyboard works great for many languages like Spanish and Portuguese. It was great to figure that out so I wouldn't have to copy/paste or try to remember alt codes.

However, in French I have to type single quotes commonly:

> S'il te plaît
>
> D'accord

Am I correct that the best way to do these on the US/International keyboard is:

```
S ' ' [backspace] i l [space] ...
D ' ' [backspace] a c c ...
```

Or is there another potential set of keystrokes that can work faster? I tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> and there is nothing like that to override the dead key? I mean aside from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+ <kbd>Shift</kbd> in and out of the keyboard mode...

Am I correct and this is the best solution, meaning US/International is kind of limited for French this way?

Answer (score 15):

I have found the solution.

On the US/International keyboard, I can type a space after the single quote. The space will be deleted and the quote will appear.

For example:

```
S ' [space] i l [space] t e ...
D ' [space] a c c ...
```

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: My hero! this does indeed solve it although it needs some time to get used to